# What is password of root?

Tags: root

I'm having some problems after changing ownership in usr folder and can not use sudo anymore. Now I'm trying to use recoverymode and after accessing grub, it asked me a password of root for maintenance but I have no idea if I have this password or not. Is there a default password of root. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: There is no password for root, unless you set one (highly discouraged).  Did you try your own password?

Comment: Yes,I did but I said failure authentication, maybe I should consider reinstalling ubuntu

Comment: You should be able to fix things from the live media running in "try" mode.  sudo will work for you from that environment.